# Views and Lists

Tags: 7, views

I would like to create a list with edit and delete buttons/links for each line.
How can I do that in drupal 7.7 ?
I know list can be created with Views module, but can I have buttons/links in the view list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit and Delete links are available to be displayed in Views. They can be added to the Views output under the Fields options.

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch your views format to "Content" (or "Display Suite" if you use this) instead of "Fields". The fields and informations which are provided there, are then configured on the view mode or the tab "Manage Display" on your content type. With this switch you get also the contextual links for each entry on the view / list like edit or delete.

If you switch to this, i would recommend you to use the "[Display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds)" module for even more possibilities on how your content type looks in different situations. Very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to expand on what @sheena_d said, you could add a custom text field to your view and custom write additional links if the edit/submit links aren't what your looking for.